# what is the best way to deserialize array of json objects without asp.net?

Tags: .net, json

what is the best way to deserialize array of json objects without asp.net?

Json format:
{"results" : [ { "a": "value A", "b": "value B"}, { "c": "value C", "d": "value D"}]}

Please note: Json object should be deserialized into .Net object.

Comment: Do you mean *with* asp.net? And if so, VB or c#?

Comment: If you're not using ASP.Net, what are you using?  Winforms?  Which language: VB, C#?

Comment: I am developing .net class library in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The Json.NET library, available here:

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx

Works great.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of implementations in different languages are provided at http://www.json.org/ (the bottom of the page)

**EDIT:** apparently that page doesn't mention the built in JSON support while it does exist in .Net 3.5 according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.aspx)

Comment: I dont want to use any third party library... It would be better if I can directly use .Net framework class library for this purpose...

Comment: The System.Runtime.Serialization.Json IS part of the .NET BCL. The DataContractJsonSerializer class does exactly what you're asking for. Don't confuse WCF with ASP.NET; they are definitely not the same. WCF does not require ASP.NET at all in order to do what it does.

Answer (score -2):

With JavaScript you'd do:

```
var myObj = eval('(' + jsonString + ')');
```

Comment: I am looking for deserializing Json object into .net objects. and not json string into json object.

Answer (score -2):

In PHP, for instance, you can do:

```
$json = json_decode($json_string);
```

and that will convert your JSON into an object/array

Comment: I am looking for deserializing Json object into .net objects. and not json string into json object.